# How to check if Navigation Controller with ID exists, iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uiwindow

I would like to check if a NavigationController with a restorationId (defined in storyboard) exists in `UIApplication.shared.windows`

If it does, I would like to check if a ViewController with ID is on that NavigationController. If it does, bring it to top of the stack, if not create an instance of the viewController and add it to the navigation stack.

This is how I am trying to achieve the above, but I am unable to go beyond printing of window.

Can someone please suggest where I am going wrong ?

```
func identifyAndPresentViewController(){

    let windows = UIApplication.shared.windows
    print("windows: \(windows)")

    for window in windows{
        print("window: \(window)")

        if let nav     = window.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {

            print("nav: \(nav)")

            let navId   = nav.restorationIdentifier
            print("navId: \(String(describing: navId))")

            if navId == "VideoCallTVCNav" {

                print("navId matches")

                let vcs = nav.viewControllers

                print("vcs: \(vcs)")

                for vc in vcs{

                    print("vc: \(vc)")

                    if vc.restorationIdentifier == "VideoCallTVC"{

                        // Display VideoCallTVC inside nav with restorationId "VideoCallTVCNav"

                        print("VideoCallTVC exists")

                    }else{

                        // Create a instance of "VideoCallTVC" and display it inside nav with restorationId "VideoCallTVCNav"

                        print("VideoCallTVC does not exists")
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, if you're not using multiple instances of UIWindow in your app just use UIApplication.shared.keyWindow. That being said, if I'm getting right what you're saying, you find a window ( the print(window: \(window)) is working ), but then you don't find any UINavigationController on the .rootViewController property right?

Comment: yes, thats correct!!

Comment: Then double check your view hierarchy as it means that there is no UINavigationController on the .rootViewController. Your code works fine and its correct ( even tough instead of using .restorationIndentifier I would have used the class type, but this is just my personal preference ). Another thing you could do is, before the "if let nav.."  print the .rootViewController so you can see what class is actually your rootViewcontroller.